# Trouble making loop run through only one if-statement and not several ones

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

I would love some help. The problem here is that when the requested dog happens to have the index of 0, the loop is working fine and only goes through the first if-statement. If the requested dog happens to have another index, both if-statements are read... Anyone who can see the solution? :)

```
protected void removeDog() {
    String k = readString("Name of dog you want to delete from list: ");
    boolean found = false;

    for (int x = 0; x < dogRegister.size(); x++) {
        if (dogRegister.get(x).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(k)) {
            dogRegister.remove(x);

            System.out.println(k + " has been deleted from list.");

            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (!found) {
            System.out.println(k + " could not be found in list.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Traversing lists with .get(i) is not very idiomatic in Java. If dogRegister is changed into a linked list, .get(i) will have cost O(n). Consider using iterators (read my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You are executing either the `if` or the `else if` each time you iterate through the `for` loop.  If it's not first, you'll get the "could not be found" message once for *each* iteration until you found it and removed it or you exhausted the list.

To have the "could not be found" message print only if you didn't find it at all, move the `else if` outside the `for` loop, removing else:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dogRegister.size(); x++) {
    if (dogRegister.get(x).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(k)) {
        dogRegister.remove(x);
        System.out.println(k + ” has been deleted from list.”);
        found = true;
        break;
     }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println(k + ” could not be found in list.");
}
```

Comment: In other words, just remove the `else` from the second `if`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but also move it out of the `for` loop, to prevent repeated "could not be found" messages.

Comment: I removed the "else", but unfortunately it didn't change anything... :( The problem remains for the dogs with index > 0.

Comment: Okay, I will try move it out of the for loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid reading a Java collection with `.get(i)` even if it is an `ArrayList`. You may use iterators, they make simple tasks easier.

```
protected void removeDog() {

    String dogName = readString("Name of dog you want to delete from list:");

    boolean found = false;

    // I assume there is a class "Dog"
    for (Iterator<Dog> it = dogRegister.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Dog dog = it.next();
        if (dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(dogName)) {
            it.remove();
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found) //print something...
    else //print something else...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void removeDog() {

    String k = readString(”Name of dog you want to delete from list: ");

    boolean found = false;

    for (int x = dogRegister.size(); x > 0; x--) {

        if (dogRegister.get(x).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(k)) {


            dogRegister.remove(x);
            System.out.println(k + ” has been deleted from list.”);
            found = true;
            break;

        }
        else if ( x == 0){
            System.out.println(k + ” could not be found in list.");
                }


        }

}
```

If you reach end of the list there will be "K could  not be found in the list".. What happened earlier is that every time it runs the loop it will always display NOT FOUND unless your dog is found in first location of your array. It will keep going until found or exit at the end.